# getJSONArray returns null when parse json object in android (java)

Tags: android, json

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("weather", "[{'id: 300,'main': 'Drizzle','description': 'light intensity drizzle','icon': '09d'}]");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
JSONObject obj2  = arr.getJSONObject(0);
```

Above is my JSON data, i am trying to extract all fields (id, main, drizzle etc) but JSONArray inside root JSON object is empty when i try to Log.d

Comment: JSONObject obj  = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jarr = null;

        try {
            obj.put("weather", "[{id: 300,main: 'ds',Drizzle : 'ww2',description: 'dfd'}]");

            jarr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            Log.d("rj", jarr.toString());
        }

Comment: I guess, you should have colon `:` after `"weather"` instead of comma `,`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON in invalid:

try this:

```
  {  
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":"300"
      },
      {  
         "main":"Drizzle"
      },
      {  
         "description":"light intensity drizzle"
      },
      {  
         "icon":"09d"
      }
   ]
}
```

you can check valid JSON using [This](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works  you forgot one ' after id

```
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        JSONArray Jarr=new JSONArray("[{'id': 300,'main': 'Drizzle','description': 'light intensity drizzle','icon': '09d'}]");
        obj.put("weather",(Object)Jarr);

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
        JSONObject obj2  = arr.getJSONObject(0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

at the first you forgot put end single quotation for id:

```
"[{'id': 300,'main': 'Drizzle','description': 'light intensity drizzle','icon': '09d'}]".
```

Second when you are using "obj.put("name", "..."}", JSONObject  get value as a String Nothing else. If you want use obj.put for  (Json array value), You should convert (string value) to (json array value) befor used On "obj.put":

```
String valueString="[{'id': 300,'main': 'Drizzle','description': 'light intensity drizzle','icon': '09d'}]"; 
JSONArray valueJsonArray=new JSONArray(valueString);
obj.put("weather",valueJsonArray);
```